# UILabel multiple lines for iPhone X is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-x

I have been working on an app and there is a label with multiple lines in it. All devices show the label correct except iPhone X. I was trying:

```
cell.lblCategoryName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.lblCategoryName.numberOfLines = 0;
[cell.lblCategoryName sizeToFit];
```

however it didn't help as well. Although the space for multiline allocated in the view, lhe label cuts the word from the end of first line. Why is that happening?

Comment: Are you using auto-layout?

Comment: Yes I created the label in storyboard.

Comment: If you're using auto-layout properly, there should be no need to manually resize anything in your code.

Comment: I just tried to resize for iPhone X. Other devices work perfectly without the code.